# android developer - check if microphone (or any hardware module) is busy

Tags: java, android

the goal of my app is to check if there is another recording app working or if the micriphone is busy / recording by. here is the code:

private MediaRecorder mRecord = null;

```
public void start() {
        if (mRecord == null) {
                mRecord = new MediaRecorder();
                mRecord.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                                    try {
                    mRecord.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mRecord.start();
        }
}

public void stop() {
        if (mRecord != null) {
                mRecord.stop();       
                mRecord.release();
                mRecord = null;
        }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCheck);
    btnCheck.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);     

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnCheck:

        if (mRecord != null) {
            mRecord.stop();       
            mRecord.release();                
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = null;
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);
            alertDialog.setTitle("You are being recorded!!!");
            alertDialog.show();
        }       

        else {

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View convertView = null;
            alertDialog.setView(convertView);
            alertDialog.setTitle("All clear");
            alertDialog.show();             

        }


        break;
```

if another app is recordind I dont get the messege "You are being recorded!!!"
any ideas to improve it?